# jQuery SELECT change trigger

Tags: jquery

I use the following jQuery function to perform a slideDown on a DIV, based on the value of a SELECT dropdown:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#show-options').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="show-options"> 
  <option value="">Select an Option</option> 
  <option value="vehicle-type">Vehicle Type</option> 
  <option value="vehicle-colour">Vehicle Colour</option> 
</select> 

<div id="vehicle-type" style="display: none;"> 
  <!--form elements in here-->
</div> 

<div id="vehicle-colour" style="display: none;"> 
  <!--form elements in here-->
</div>
```

Now when the form is submitted, any DIVs that were displayed before submission need to be displayed automatically. I can check for the GET variables in my PHP but I need the jQuery code that will mimic the 'change' function - I think this has something to do with triggers or binds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this a lot actually.  The easiest way I've found is to just trigger the event after binding it like so:

```
function showByVal(val) {
    $('#' + val).slideDown();
}

$(function()
{
    $('#show-options').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            showByVal($(this).val());
        }
    });

    showByVal('<? echo $_GET["PreviousVal"]; ?>');
});
```

As long as the value is set ahead of time (by your PHP Code) then the event will fire after it binds and setup the initial display.

Comment: How is this going to work if the user has shown more than one of the sections? You'd have to run through each of the selections and trigger the change event after setting it as the selected value.  The code doesn't appear to do a toggle, just a reveal of each section that has been chosen so multiple can be open at the same time.

Comment: @tvanfosson - That's true, it does not appear to toggle, but from the question it's not 100% clear whether the OP is posting back to the same page, or to another one.  If he's posting to the same page, and needs the display to be consistent after posting / refreshing then the PHP code can set one of the `<option>` tags as selected based on the GET variable and then the jQuery code updates the display appropriately.  I was more addressing the "how do I trigger an event I've bound" part of the question, which this works wonderfully for.

Comment: This is for a search form using GET. It submits to the same page. There is a possibility that multiple DIVs will need to be displayed but that's not a problem as I can check for the GET variables in my PHP code.

Comment: @GSTAR - Is your `<select>` a multi-select (it does not appear to be from the provided code)?  If so the event handler may need some minor modification in order for this approach to work.

Comment: No, it's just a single select. I think what I need to do is pass in the VALUE of the selected option into the trigger so that the change function knows what $(this).val() is.

Comment: @GSTAR - You shouldn't need to as long as your PHP code sets it up ahead of time.  `<option value="vehicle-type" selected="selected">Vehicle Type</option>` would be enough.

Comment: @gddc - The dropdown option is being selected, but the DIV is still hidden. I need the div to be displayed IF it was displayed before form submission.

Comment: @GSTAR - That's kind of unexpected based on what you've provided.  You should end up with at least one div displayed.  Is it that only one is displaying, or are all of them hidden at this point?  Can you add an alert / log call in the event handler and verify what `$(this).val()` is returning when the page loads the second time?

Comment: Oh OK I understand what you're trying to say. The thing is I'm not setting the value of the SELECT dropdown upon form submission because that doesn't help the user. Instead it will always default to the "empty" option ("Select an Option"). This is why I think it needs to be done using a trigger.

Comment: So basically I need to pass in the value of a dropdown option into the trigger so that it runs the change function for that value.

Comment: @GSTAR - I think I understand what you're saying.  Let me update the example code up above a bit.

Comment: To also catch changes in the dropdown caused by keypress (arrow-keys or alphanums) you should change this 
$('#show-options').change(function(){ ...  });
to
$('#show-options').bind('change keyup',function() { ... });

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#" + $("#show-options :selected").val()).slideDown();
```

of course you'll have to write in php the selected attribute to the right option

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in response to form submission, why not simply show the DIV (i.e., not make the style "display: none;") when you render the page for those things that have been displayed.  You'd need to either keep track, using hidden fields would be one way, or only show those sections that have both been displayed and had an item in the section selected.  Either way you can use the inputs that you get from the form to determine which sections have the default visibility set to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to do something like this I'll do `$('#ele').trigger('change')` thus not having to do anything special so when the page loads it just triggers the change event of the select list and as long as the correct value is set once the page loads it calls your already defined change handler.